# How to invoke a gwt service from c client?

Tags: java, c, gwt, xml-rpc, gwt-rpc

I'm looking for a simple way to invoke a GWT service from C client. For the Server side I'm using the simple Gwt default source:

```
public String greetServer(String input) throws IllegalArgumentException {
    // Verify that the input is valid. 
    if (!FieldVerifier.isValidName(input)) {
        // If the input is not valid, throw an IllegalArgumentException Back to:
        // the client.
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                "Name must be at least 4 characters long");
    }

    String serverInfo = getServletContext().getServerInfo();
    String userAgent = getThreadLocalRequest().getHeader("User-Agent");

    // Escape data from the client to avoid cross-site script vulnerabilities.
    input = escapeHtml(input);
    userAgent = escapeHtml(userAgent);

    return "Hello, " + input + "!<br><br>I am running " + serverInfo
            + ".<br><br>It looks like you are using:<br>" + userAgent;
}
```

Now I've to create an RPC call from the C client that will call `greetServer` with a `String` parameter. So what kind of libraries do I have to use and how can I identify this service (`greetServer`)  in the client side. I've found this [library](http://xmlrpc-c.sourceforge.net/) but I don't know if it'll work for me.

Any Ideas?